# scala match expression avoiding code duplication

Tags: scala

Say I am using a match expression to test a value that may or may not be in a Map object as follows:

```
map.get(key) match {
  case Some(value) if (cond1(value)) => res1(value)
  case Some(value) if (cond2(value)) => res2()
  case None => res2()
  case _ => // None of the above
}
```

As you can see I want to call the res2 in either case where I have a value for my key and it meets condition 2 or I have no value for key. Can anyone suggest a better construct that would avoid the duplicate calls to res2() in the sample above?

Thanks
Des

*** Sorry I realised that the code sample was not quite correct and have updated accordingly. I only want to call res2 in the case where the value for the key meets cond2 OR there is NO entry for key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is:

```
map.get(key) match {
  case Some(value) if (cond1(value)) => res1(value)
  case o: Option[String] if ( o.forall(cond2) ) => res2()
  case _ => 
}
```

replacing [`String`] with whatever the type of `key` is.

The names of the methods on Option aren't always the most obvious; in maintaining functional purity they sacrifice clarity for us illiterati.  In this case, the [scaladoc for Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) tells us that forall:

> Returns true if this option is empty or the predicate p returns true
>   when applied to this scala.Option's value.

Comment: This is the best answer if the OP is not expecting side effects from `cond2`, which (s)he shouldn't.

Comment: The OP updated his question and made this answer invalid: he wants to call `res2()` if the value associated with `key` matches `cond2`, or there is no value associated with `key`. This answer will also call it if there is a value associated with `key` that matches neither `cond1` nor `cond2`.

Comment: @user79074 Answer updated to match updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Without gard if that are only possibilities:

```
case Some(value) => if (cond1(value) ) res1(value) else res2()
```